# Vue.js Displaying data from websocket into a table and sending data to other component

Tags: vue.js, websocket

Version: Vue CLI 2.6.x

I am trying to resolve two issues:

Issue 1:
My Vue app has subscribed to updates via a websocket. I am getting the data continuously and need to keep the table updated with the received data. However the table remains empty even when the list (aqiDataList) has content in it.

Issue 2:
I also need to pass the aqiDataList to the AQITableComponent (where the actual table was originally suppose to be) but having this same issue

App.vue

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <AQITableComponent :aqiList="aqiDataList" />
        <v-simple-table>
            <template v-slot:default>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-left">
                            Age
                        </th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr
                    v-for="item in aqiDataList"
                    :key="item.id"
                    >
                        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.age }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.location }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </template>
        </v-simple-table>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import AQITableComponent from './AQITableComponent';

export default {
    name: 'AQIComponent',
    components: {
        AQITableComponent
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            connection: null,
            aqiDataList: []
        };
    },
    mounted() {
    
    },
    methods: {
        
    },
    created: function () {
        console.log("Starting connection to WebSocket Server");
        this.connection = new WebSocket("wss://my-websocket.com");

        this.connection.onmessage = function (event) {
            //console.log(event.data);
            let aqiDataString = event.data;
            this.aqiDataList = [];

            let parsedData = JSON.parse(aqiDataString);

            parsedData.forEach((aqiData) => {
                
                this.aqiDataList.push({
                    ... object
                });
            });

            console.log(this.aqiDataList);
        };

        this.connection.onopen = function (event) {
            console.log(event);
            console.log("Successfully connected to the echo websocket server...");
        };
    },
}
</script>
```

AQITableComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-simple-table>
            <template v-slot:default>
                .. same table as shown above
            </template>
        </v-simple-table>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'AQITableComponent',
    props: ['aqiList'],
    data: function () {

    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: I not sure if pushing to an array maintains reactivity.  See [Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).  Also, is there any reason you can't just say ```this.aqiDataList = parsedData```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Try using the arrow function for the onmessage event:

from: `this.connection.onmessage = function (event) {...}`

to: `this.connection.onmessage = (event) => {...}`

or: `this.connection.addEventListener("message", (event) => {...});`

This way the `this.aqiDataList`  will be available on your component. Inside the event callback.

This should also solve the problem (2) since your array is not being updated on the first place.

Comment: Can't believe it was this simple. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're not alone check this article if you want more input https://michaelnthiessen.com/this-is-undefined/

Comment: Thanks for the resources :)